# libusb is not enumerating devices

Tags: windows, usb, windows-7-x64, libusb

Using `libusb 1.2.6` I am trying to enumerate all devices on Windows 7 x64.

MinGW is my IDE and project is linked to `gcc/libusb.a`. Not sure if this one will do the job on `x64`.

This is the code, taken from examples:

```
usb_init(); /* initialize the library */
usb_find_busses(); /* find all busses */
usb_find_devices(); /* find all connected devices */

struct usb_bus *busses = usb_get_busses();

for (bus = busses; bus; bus = bus->next) {
        struct usb_device *dev;

        for (dev = bus->devices; dev; dev = dev->next) {
            /* Check if this device is a printer */
            if (dev->descriptor.bDeviceClass == 7) {
                /* Open the device, claim the interface and do your processing */

            }

            /* Loop through all of the configurations */
            for (c = 0; c < dev->descriptor.bNumConfigurations; c++) {
                /* Loop through all of the interfaces */
                for (i = 0; i < dev->config[c].bNumInterfaces; i++) {
                    /* Loop through all of the alternate settings */
                    for (a = 0; a < dev->config[c].interface[i].num_altsetting; a++) {
                        /* Check if this interface is a printer */
                        if (dev->config[c].interface[i].altsetting[a].bInterfaceClass == 7) {
                            /* Open the device, set the alternate setting, claim the interface and do your processing */

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It can find 1 bus, but then no devices. I was expecting to see all connected devices.

Eventually what I want is to establish bulk transfer on specific device which already has a driver.

Comment: The code here doesn't really show or output anything, is this the actual code ?

Comment: yes this is actual code. I'm using step over debug.

Comment: So could it be that libusb can't enumerate/open devices which already have non-libusb drivers? And in order to open device with non-libusb driver I have to use `install-filter`? Is it true or there is some way to open existing driver with lib-usb without installing anything? If anyone could elaborate on this I would appreciate it.

Comment: Maybe it is too late now, but I am having the same problem. I get one bus and no devices. However, after installing the inf file generated by the `inf-wizard` and plugging in the device I am getting one bus and one device. I guess that your guess that `install-filter` is required to see all devices is correct.